# Dependency injection in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm straggling to reach the correct structure with spring's dependency injection.
I have a common subproject that is shared between multiple project. It has the following interface and class:

```
public interface ICommonConfigurationService 
public class CommonConfigurationService implements ICommonConfigurationService
```

I added @service at the implementation so it could be injected.

In another project that depends on the common project, I have:

```
public interface IConfigurationService extends ICommonConfigurationService 
public class ConfigurationService extends CommonConfigurationService implements IConfigurationService
```

because in the scope of the subproject that depends on common, I want to be able to access the implementation and functions of the common file from above.
The issue is, in the scope of the subproject- I want it to access the subproject implementation - ConfigurationService. But, in the scope of the common project, I want it to inject the CommonConfigurationService implementation.

I can't define both of them as @Service, because in the subproject it yells that it has 2 qualifying beans. I also can't remove @Service from common, because tests in the common project can't find implementation that way.

I hope my issue is clear and would appreciate you assistance with the correct structure/annotation.

Comment: Yes you can define both. Mark the one you want to use  with `@Primary`, or don't mark yours and add an `@Bean` method which would override the bean created with `@Service` or/and exclude the one you don't need from component scanning (that is what the exclude filters are for).

Answer (score 1):

In case of ambiguous definition of a Spring Component (Service in your case) you can use the `@Qualifier` annotation to distinguish them.